# Get certain part of url in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get version no part from a url. Url will look like this "http://myweb.com/api/v1/customer". I need to get the "1" value from the url. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the pattern? Get the only number which is in the url?

Comment: I need to get the version no. The url is always "*/api/v*/*". I need to get the "v1" value or just the "1"

Comment: if version can be anywhere in url then `api/v(.+)/` regex will capture version in group `\1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lookaround assertions like below,

```
Regex.Match(yourstring, @"(?<=/v)\d+(?=/)").Value;
```

- `(?<=/v)` Positive lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by `/v`
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.
- `(?=/)` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by a forward-slash `/` character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/13)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code looks more simple. I modify your code a bit to "Regex.Match(yourstring, @"(?<=/api/v)\d+(?=/)").Value;"

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Uri` class, which has a built in parser specifically for parsing uris, and exposes a nice API for examining the components of the URI.

```
Uri uri = new UriBuilder("http://myweb.com/api/v1/customer").Uri;
string versionString = uri.Segments[2]; // v1/
```

You can, of course, further process this to extract just the number, as shown in the next snippet. The benefit is that you won't have to worry about complicated edge cases in parsing URIs with your regex.

```
int version = int.Parse(Regex.Match(versionString, @"\d+").Value);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://ideone.com/4kgey7

Comment: Does it work if the url is "www.myweb.com/api/v1/customer" or "myweb.com/api/v1/customer"?

Comment: @Reynaldi Not with the URI constructor. If you want fault tolerant URI parsing, you can use `new UriBuilder(yourURIString).Uri`;

Comment: `\d+` would return any number not only the one next to `/v`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, but since we've already extracted only the `v1/` segment of the URI, we can use a naive regex like `\d+` against the extracted URI segment. If you've spotted a case where this code works incorrectly, please fork the demo and change the string to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are using MVC you can use attribute routing:

```
[GET("api/v{version:int}/customer")]
public ActionResult GetCustomer(int version) {
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=v)\d+
```

You can use this simple regex to do that.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/36

Answer (score -1):

```
string line = "http://myweb.com/api/v1/customer"
string[] arr = line.Split('\');

foreach(string str in arr)
{
    if(str[0] == 'v')
    {
       int v = Convert.ToInt32(str.SubString(1));
    }
}
```